# File corruption when uploading image files to S3 via PUT request (Amazon S3 Proxy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I've been using this tutorial (particularly the part about uploading/downloading binary files) as a guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

My issue is that when I upload jpg/png files to S3 via AWS S3 Proxy, the files end up corrupted. They end up having slightly larger file sizes once they end up in S3. This is not the case for the text files I upload via my PUT requests - their file sizes do not change & I have no issue opening & reading them in my browser.

As the above guide, I made sure to add all the file types I was uploading to my Binary Media Type List. I also require Content-Type in my header (this is currently the only thing I'm including in my header, as I haven't set up API keys yet - is there anything I'm missing). The file types in my Binary Media Type List are:

image/png

image/jpg

text/plain.

Finally, I've made sure to set Content Handling to Passthrough, as the tutorial recommends. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried sending my data as an encoded 64 bit string (not sure if this is required) but the issue persists. (I've also sent it as un-enconded data). I'm using python3 & the requests library to make my requests. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: did you solve the issue? I'm experiencing exactly the same problem.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked on this, but I think my issue came from not enabling CORS in my API Gateway

Answer (score -1):

For future references this issue is mainly because of handling binary data in API Gateway, and has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800188)