# PDF Uploaded via AWS API Gateway getting corrupted

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

I am trying to uploading a PDF via a web form into an S3 bucket using a C# Web API that I have deployed to the AWS API gateway.

Here is my code:

```
 private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;


        public static async Task<string> UploadS3FileAsync(string bucketName, IFormFile file, string keyName)  
        {
            try
            {  

                s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();      
                var fileTransferUtility =  new TransferUtility(s3Client);

                //Upload data from a type of System.IO.Stream.
                var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                var length = (int)stream.Length;
                byte[] data = new byte[length];

                stream.Read(buffer: data, offset: 0, count: length);

               var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest

                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    InputStream = stream,
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                    ContentType = "application/pdf",
                    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB.
                    Key = keyName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.NoACL
                };

                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest); 

                return "success";

            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
                //Console.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
                //Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }

        }
```

This works perfectly when I run the process locally, but when I deploy the API to the gateway, the PDF, although uploaded into the bucket is corrupted and is larger than the original file.

I have tried various things like setting the Binary Media Type on the API gateway, various types of creating the stream. I'm sure it has something to do with encoding, but I'm not sure where to go next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the purpose of the `stream.Read` line? I think that the S3 library might do this for you, but generally you should seek back to the starting point before reusing the stream.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for your reply. I have tried a number of different ways of creating the stream and that was my most recent attempt. I will try to remove that line and see if it makes any difference though.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it will help, if you're getting a bigger object on S3 than you uploaded. That seems strange.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and got the same result. The original PDF is around 116kB and the uploaded document is over 200kB. When I open the document in Chrome it says "Failed to load PDF document" I have tried to inspect the PDF, and it does seem to have some valid PDF data in it, but I'm stumped as to why it is not uploading properly.

Comment: Any luck on figuring this out? Facing the same thing. Have a feeling API Gateway is the culprit. I've tried setting up the "Binary Media Types" setting (and Deploy), but still doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4):

This is what solved it for me:

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/635

1. In settings under binary media type heading create an entry for `multipart/form-data`.
2. Create a new model with the below configuration.

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "MediaFileUpload",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
   "file": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

3. Modify the method request step adding adding an entry under "Request Body" using the model as a content type of `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: God, its working! You have saved the day. From all the solution, this solution is the only one that worked for me. I added the `multipart/form-data` to my `template.yml` from AWS SAM CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the "Binary Media Types" in the settings tab?

API Gateway by default considers all request payload as text data, i.e., non-binary data, and performs a base64-encoding on the payload. The larger PDF you've got should be a file containing the base64-encoded version of the original PDF.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I eventually went the route of getting a pre-signed URL to allow client-side uploads instead and it is working well.

Ref: https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d